# How can I append an item from a class method to a list inside another class?

Tags: python, list, class, class-method, python-class

I want to append an item to the list in `Class A` but when I call the list after the process, it just return an empty list. How exactly can I successfully append an item?

This is what I tried. I implement `lst.append` inside the `getAnswer` method but the appending was unsuccessful. Note that I only included snippet of my code because there are other things going on there. I am just concerned on knowing how can I successfully to the appending function.

```
class A:
  lst = []

class B:
  *#I implemented distance formula here*

class C: 
  def __init__(self, pt, tolerance):
    self.pt = pt

  def getAnswer(self, tolerance):
    self.tolerance = tolerance

    d = B(p1,p2).dist
    if d <= self.tolerance:
       lst.append(p2)

p_list = [p1, p2]
a = C(p_list, 7)

A.lst
```

Comment: @Sayse it means that p2 is a neighbor of p1

Comment: @Sayse my bad, the code should have been d = B(p1,p2).dist where self.dist is an attribute of class B.

Comment: @Sayse the problem is that when I tried to append the item into the list and calls the list, it only returns an empty list

Comment: I think correct scoping should work, as per my answer below

Comment: It would be empty because you never call `getAnswer` so nothing ever modifies the list

Comment: @Sayse will it not work if I directly append to list? I'm new to programming so I have a hard time comprehending. How can I call the `getAnswer`?

Comment: `C.getAnswer(whateveryourtoleranceis)`

Comment: You may want to do some research around class inheritance / subclassing. Your approach seems to be conceptually wrong

Answer (score 0):

Theres lots of things wrong with your question so I've bullet pointed them and then updated your snippet.

- your instance of `C` is called `a` which is confusing
- You pass in tolerance to your `C` initializer and never use it,
- `lst` is a class variable of `A` but you aren't using it, instead you're making a new variable of the same name in your `getAnswer` function
- `getAnswer` is never called.
- `getAnswer` never "gets" anything so the function name is a bit misleading (havent modified)
- you initiate B with two variables `p1,p2` which don't exist in the scope of the function, but already exist in your `pt` list

```
class A:
  lst = []

class B:
  *#I implemented distance formula here*

class C: 
  def __init__(self, pt):
    self.pt = pt
    self.tolerance = None

  def getAnswer(self, tolerance):
    self.tolerance = tolerance

    d = B(self.pt[0],self.pt[1]).dist
    if d <= self.tolerance:
       A.lst.append(p2)

p_list = [p1, p2]
c = C(p_list)
c.getAnswer(7)
A.lst
```

Whilst the above will update your list, its still odd to have `C` change A's list, I've left it as is because there are valid use cases and the variable names are too vague too suggest otherwise.

Answer (score -2):

It does not work, because lst is a local variable inside the class/function. I would do:

```
class A:
    global lst
    lst = []
class C:
    #init
    def getAnswer(self, tolerance):
        #stuff
        #if
            lst.append(p2)
```

Here is a test:

```
>>> class A:
    global lst
    lst = []

>>> class C:
    def __init__(self):
        lst.append("This is appended to the list!")

>>> C()
<__main__.C object at 0x0000021D25CF5640>
>>> """I just called the C __init__ function, let's see if it worked"""
"I just called the C __init__ function, let's see if it worked"
>>> print(lst)
['This is appended to the list!']
>>> """Yay!"""
'Yay!'
>>>
```

Comment: By the way: Global variables are not the best, but in some cases they are necessary. If the file is not huge, it should not be a problem to have a few global ones as long as you remember not to use that name inside functions.

Comment: This is not one of those cases where they are necessary, I don't think I've ever used the `global` keyword in my code so I don't even think there is a case

Comment: Well, you could of course try making it return a value and then assigning that value to lst. But still, I think that would be way too complicated to be functional.

Comment: Initializing a global variable at class creation, in a place where it would be expected to be a class attribute if not for the `global ...` just above, also might be rather confusing...

Comment: Even `A.lst` would be better than declaring it global.

Comment: @norway-yv - Done, that would only help the OP though and the reason for my comment here is you're more than likely to suggest `global` on other answers which in my opinion isn't going to help yourself or others with their issues.